# Why can't I call .capitalize method on my Ruby object?

Tags: ruby, string

Here is the test code for Ruby.

```
class Me  
  puts "i am me"
end

who = Me.new

myself = who.capitalize
```

I would expect that the string "I am me" would return, but I am mistaken. Ruby doesn't recognize the .capitalize method for a newly created object from a unique class. It's fine with returning who as the "i am me" string, but if I try to call .capitalize it doesn't recognize the method. Why?

Comment: wow, serious and fundamental misunderstandings going on here... :)

Comment: Indeed. Serious understanding does not often come from a trivial "quote" - misunderstanding.

Comment: When you fail, fail spectacularly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the method `capitalize` is defined in the `String` class.

First of all, in the line `puts "i am me"` you are just *executing* the method `puts`. Once executed, the string "i am me" is gone, because you don't hold any reference to it, and it has nothing to do with the class Me.

Perhaps this code reflects what you try to do

```
class Me

  # Returns the string, can be executed by instances of class Me
  def to_s
    "i am me"
  end

end

puts Me.new.to_s.capitalize
```

Comment: this code does exactly what I intended. I defined a new variable called 'myself' as Me.new.to_s and operated puts on it as 'puts myself' and then 'puts myself.capitalize' This illustrates many facets for me. Many thanks. Regards.

Comment: Try to play around in irb with Ruby code, as you've got some misunderstanding as other people pointed out. Try to figure out why and how does the code above work, we're here to help ;)

Comment: thank you for suffering a autodidact. It's one thing to read a book and say "yeah, okay. I get it" and then to put the book away and start writing code.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought all Ruby objects can call .capitalize method

No. You can call `some_obj.some_method` if and only if the class of `some_obj` or one of its superclasses or included modules defines the method `some_method`. This means that for a method to be callable on any object, it needs to be defined in the `Object` class, which is the superclass of all classes, (or one of its included modules).

`capitalize` is not defined on `Object` it is defined on `String` and for good reason. `42.capitalize` or `[].capitalize` would make no sense.

```
class Me  
  puts "i am me"
end
```

This code probably doesn't do what you think it does. When the class definition of `Me` is first read, the string `i am me` will be printed. This does not define any behaviour of the `Me` class. Basically it's the same as:

```
class Me  
end
puts "i am me"
```

I.e. you're creating an empty class.

If your intention was that the string `i am me` should be printed every time you do `Me.new`, `puts "i am me"` needs to be placed in `Me`'s `initialize` method. But even so, you won't be able to call `String` methods on `Me` objects.

Also you seem to be under the impression that you can change a string after it has already been printed. This is of course not possible. Once you call `puts` on a string, it appears on the screen and you can't take it back (well you could using `termios` or terminal-specific control sequences, but that's not the point).

Comment: Alright, my mistake to think .capitalize was defined on Object when it's defined on String.

Comment: @Milktrader, try and understand _why_ it's a mistake...it doesn't actually make SENSE for such a method to exist on all objects. How would you capitalize the number '5' for example?

Comment: thanks much for the response. I've re-read your answer many times and it's helpful.

Comment: @banister I got off on the wrong floor, but I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in my docs, only `String` and `Symbol` have `capitalize` method. So only them and their child classes have it.